# Обсуждения "оффтопики" в чате

Tags: поддержка, чат

Модератор PashaPash написал [следующее сообщение](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42271745#42271745)

> уважаемые посетители чата. на мой взгляд, причины снятия владельцев были подробно расписаны тем, кто это снятие произвел. если вам нужны дополнительные пояснения - обратитесь, пожалуйста, к нашему CM. не стоит приходить в чат и еще раз устраивать "а объясните лично мне". с данного момента **объявляю продолжение обсуждения** в стиле "а я все-таки не понял, за что сняли овнеров" **оффтопиком**.

(выделение - моё)

1. Это вообще законно? мы должны это исполнять?
2. Если да - что значит "посетители чата"? конкнетно этой чат-комнаты или вообще всех комнат chat.stackexchange.com ?
3. Откуда посетители чата должны узнать от этом решении модератора?
4. Существуют ли другие запрещенные темы для обсуждений?

Comment: Поддерживаю вопрос.

Comment: @VladD это pinned сообщение в чате. я посчитал, что замораживать комнату ради прекращения  - слишком жестокая мера. что является онтопиком, и должна ли "официальная" комната чем-то отличаться в плане офтопика от остальных, должны ли в ней применяться другие правила - хороший вопрос.

Comment: @PashaPash через 2 недели за"pin"утое сообщение спадёт (а в мобильной версии этой панели вообще нет).. что делать дальше? и что делать тем, кто не видит панели в мобильнике?

Comment: @PashaPash, там видна только часть сообщения. Ответьте на остальные части вопроса, ASAP.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я уже написал выше - я пытался избежать заморозки комнаты. думаю, двух недель не потребуется, все остынут через пару часов

Comment: Коллеги, предложу остановить беседу в целях выяснения последнего по списку (но первого по значению) вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

С моей точки зрения, выбором тем для обсуждения в чате должно заниматься сообщество, а не модераторы. Напомню, решение об отделении политоты в отдельный чат было принято коллективно, а не единоличным решением. Также напомню, что модераторы поставлены, чтобы выполнять волю сообщества, а не навязывать ему свою волю. Модератор — это избранный чиновник, а не самодержец.

С моей точки зрения, тема может быть запрещена к обсуждению в чате, если (1) она противоречит правилам ресурса, или (2) против этой темы проголосовало сообщество.

PS: Я бы хотел, чтобы правила ресурса были сформулированы чётко, на отдельной странице. Абстракный бинайс кажется мне слишком субъективным понятием.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6736 для P.S.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) это вообще законно? мы должны это исполнять?

Не знаю, насколько законно, но по этой теме уже был создан вопрос на мете с кучей ответов к нему. И комментарии к вопросам/ответам там более подходящее для этого место, на мой взгляд. Если же обсуждения в комментариях недостаточно, можно создать отдельную комнату в чате для продолжения беседы, а не забивать одной этой тематикой общую чат комнату на русском.

> 2) если да - что значит "посетители чата"? конкнетно этой чат-комнаты или вообще всех комнат chat.stackexchange.com ?

По обращению "уважаемые посетители чата" в **данной конкретной** комнате, можно с уверенностью говорить, что речь идёт про один конкретный чат.

> 3) откуда посетители чата должны узнать от этом решении модератора?

Уже узнали с вашей помощью.

> 4) существуют ли другие запрещенные темы для обсуждений?

Безусловно.