# Правила межличностного поведения и взаимного уважения

Tags: обсуждение, чат

По мотивам инициативы @NicolasChabanovsky:

> Коллеги, давайте на Мете соберём список спорных моментов касательно
>   взаимного уважения.

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42272176#42272176

Собственно давайте здесь и составим список этих самых "спорных моментов" и возможно правил.

Comment: Пустая трата времени и сил. Если участники не могут общаться нормально без правил, то их создание только подтолкнет к обсуждению трактовок и тыкания в какие-то пункты.

Comment: Это всё же лучше, чем вести себя по-хамски, пару тройку раз пообсуждают некоторые пункты, побудут заблокированы за их нарушение и успокоятся.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что список должны писать самые обидчивые и ранимые. Ибо если воспринимать всё адекватно и не выдумывать того, чего не было сказано  - то никакой список не нужен.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мы с вами незнакомы, как к вам предпочтительнее обращаться на ты или на вы? И как обращаться к людям, по умолчанию? На ты, а если они предпочитают на вы? Перед этим уточнять или как? Это всё как пример уважительного отношения к собеседнику и это должно быть чётко определено. В дружественных кругах знакомых людей совсем другое дело, правда и там есть свои негласные правила.

Comment: @edem вот определим мы тут, что обращаться надо сразу на "Ты", а всех, кто будет на "Вы" что - банить?)) ЛОЛ. ну Вас нафиг))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет, сначала в ссылку на мету, только не все правила можно классифицировать на чёрное и белое.

Comment: А давайте посмотрим на то, что уже флагали ранее? Подтвержденные тревоги, прецедентное право. Мы будем искать н-слово в черной комнате, когда в эту комнату отродясь ни одного н-слово не заходило?

Comment: @AK да, это отличный вариант, только обсуждение следует продолжить в основном вопросе теперь уже.

Comment: @AK в афроамерикаснкой комнате же.