# Что есть оскорбление и чем можно кого-то обидеть?

Tags: обсуждение

Данный вопрос — инициатива по сбору неочевидных **с персональной точки зрения** (то есть субъективных по определению) выражений, интонаций, фактов и тд. В общем всего, что может как–либо обидеть или задеть вас или ваших коллег.

Собрав список являющихся и не являющихся (лишь в нашем культурном пространстве) оскорблениями фраз, я с помощью моих коллег, смогу его уточнить и дополнить объяснениями, почему что–то можно, а чего–то стоит избежать контексте сосуществования множества культур на одном сервисе. По результатам обсуждения, я создам новый раздел справочного центра нашего сообщества.

Список может и должен пополняться в будущем! Если вас что–то тревожит или вам сказали, что что–то кого–то оскорбляет, но вы несогласны, пожалуйста, добавьте фразу, и мы рассмотрим ее вместе, дадим необходимые пояснения.

Мне кажется, что было бы удобно построить обсуждение в два ответа.

- В первый, пожалуйста, добавляйте все спорные на ваш взгляд выражения, которые вы лично оскорбительными не считаете, но вам кто–либо явно сказал, что так делать не стоит.
- Во второй, пожалуйста, добавляйте все фразы, которые вы лично считаете оскорблениями, но почему–то другие так не считают. Пожалуйста, по возможности (настоятельно рекомендую) добавляйте разъяснение, почему эта фраза может кого–либо оскорбить, когда ее использовать не стоит, когда она допустима (если такое возможно).

Огромная просьба не писать нецензурной лексики. Это запрещено правилами сообщества. Вопрос именно о том, что может обидеть вас или ваших коллег, но другие участники об этом не догадываются. Пожалуйста, если вас что–либо когда–либо задевало, опубликуйте это!

**Не следует добавлять не имеющие для вас огромной значимости вещи. Например, хотя я сам обоими руками за использования «вы» на сайте и в чате и сам соблюдаю это правило, мне совершенно не критично, если ко мне обратятся на «ты». Я бы это правило не добавил.**

*Расскажите нам, как правильно построить диалог с вами, чтобы все получали от этого удовольствие!*

---

Пожалуйста, если вы хотите внести какие–либо дополнения/изменения/комментарии **приватно**, напишите их мне на почту nicolas.chabanovsky@stackoverflow.com. Я добавлю их анонимно (от себя).

Comment: Непонятно, как голосовать за ответы. Что означает голос «за»?

Comment: И ещё непонятна цель этого опроса. Собираемся ли мы запретить всё, что может оскорбить любого из высказавшихся здесь участников?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6736 закройте как дубликат сразу.

Comment: @VladD Согласен. Вторая проблема — обсуждение. Если у вас есть более удачные идеи, пожалуйста, давайте их воплотим!

Comment: Давайте уберём акцент со слова "в чате", есть ещё комментарии к вопросам и ответам например.

Comment: @edem: Не согласен, проблема чата стоит сейчас особенно остро. Давайте решать проблемы одну за другой.

Comment: Эээ, у нас только что было, что то, что модераторы не считают нарушением, приходящие варяги считают им. Предлагается создать местный список, снова входит варяг и очередной кризис? Институциональная колея, однако.

Comment: @edem Да-да! Поправил!

Comment: @AK Ниже есть два ответа. В первый мы вносим то, что вы/мы/я оскорблением не считаем, но нам говорят, что так делать не надо. Во второй, то, что мы считаем оскорблением, а другие почему–то нет. Со временем, я буду уточнять термины из первого ответа у коллег и добавлять к ним объяснение, почему конкретную фразу не стоит использовать и в каком контексте, вероятно, перенося ее во второй ответ. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно более детально, в чем именно ваш вопрос или возражение? Очень хочется учесть все нюансы!

Comment: @VladD Предположу, что оптимальное развитие ситуации выглядит как сбор _адекватных_ правил, которые покроют максимум вопросов **текущего** конфликта интересов. Прям все–все, думаю, учитывать не стоит (да и не получится). Возникнут новые проблемы, внесем дополнения.

Comment: @edem действенный способ: начать друг друга оскорблять и получить список в итоге. Должно быть быстро, как пуля.

Comment: @alexolut через 417 дней получим результат?)

Comment: @alexolut Оружием тоже можно убить. И что, нам всем без электричества сидеть теперь?

Comment: Так и вспоминается эта хохма: "- Господин председательствующий, будет ли считаться нарушением, если я назову сэра Генри сволочью? - Несомненно, назвав сэра Генри сволочью, вы нарушите регламент и правила приличия! - Спасибо! В таком случае, сэр генри, я не буду называть вас сволочью..." Ну или "- Сэр, немедленно извинитесь за то, что вы назвали сэра Генри сволочью! - О, конечно! [далее, увы, надо передать интонацией] Сэр Генри - не сволочь? извините!" Я к тому, что автоматизировать такое тонкое, контекстно-зависимое понятие, как оскорбление - нереально.

Comment: При том, что у каждого свой порог чувствительности, к тому же зависящий от текущего психологического :) состояния... Поэтому лично я считаю, что из этой затеи - хорошо это или плохо - но ничего не выйдет. Потому модераторы и люди, а не программы...

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky интересная связь "оружие - электричество". Не могли бы её пояснить, пожалуйста? А заодно, я бы не прочь услышать причину бана в чате на 4 дня, другие забаненные ранее могут приревновать, как мне кажется.

Comment: @alexolut [Легко!](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ.

Comment: вы хотите примеры конкретных фраз без контекста, которые оскорбляют? Для чего? Какую задачу вы хотите решить? Похоже на XY-задачу. Если это попытка реализовать be-nice политику, чтобы более дружелюбную атмосферу создать в комментариях, в текстах вопросов/ответов, в чате, на Мете, то одна мера (тем более настолько узко-техническая) вряд ли положительный результат даст.¶ В качестве альтернативы можно продвигать рекомендации *"не говорите того что лицом к лицу не сказали бы"*, *"предполагайте добрые намерения"* (не называйте авторов тунеядцами). По спорным моментам, обсуждение на Мете заводить¶

Comment: Мне это напоминает Stop button задачу  из AI (здесь роль опасного AI выполняет нежелательное поведение("оскорбления"). Есть решение, которое на людях может работать https://youtu.be/9nktr1MgS-A (кратко: общий интеллект (люди/тролли) любые правила извратят. Лучше непрямые инициативы использовать: общность целей).

Comment: @jfs Спасибо за ссылку и рекомендации! Обдумывая этот вопрос, я [пришел](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42305163#42305163) примерно к тем же заключениям. Данная инициатива — отзыв на просьбы ([например](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41297965#41297965),но просьбы подобные были ни один раз) конкретных участников попробовать дать формальное определение. Я предложил формат, в котором мы с большей вероятностью получим како–либо результат. Как его получим, будем двигаться дальше.

Answer (score -4):

## Неочевидные выражения, которые вы не считаете оскорбительными, но другие считают

- Фанатик — найдено [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5568).
- Категоричный акцент на утверждении, что "ваше мнение меня не волнует", когда задают личный вопрос на Мете ([источник](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4017))
- Упоминание имён пользователей в вопросах, когда суть вопроса может быть обезличена, без потери смыслов.
- "Иди гугли" и тому подобные отсылки в поисковики.
- Русское написание "на Украине" для украинцев и "Белоруссия" для белорусов, написание "в Украине" или "Беларусь" для русских
- называть конечных пользователей ПО "юзерами"

Comment: Про фильм Трон не ясно. @Kromster, поясните, пожалуйста, идею?

Comment: Если пользователь в профиле не указал, что он из Украины – по дефолту считается, что он русский и оскорбляться на момент в/на Украине не имеет права. Я не вижу других способов соблюсти этот пункт, если пользователь не указывает своё местоположение или не отмечает в профиле что его анноит. Делать каждый раз поиск по всему чату?

Comment: @AK У меня много друзей как из Украины, так и из Белорусии. Для себя (лично для себя) я сделал следующий вывод: если я хочу общаться с данными людьми и они крайне сильно настраивают на каком–то обращении к ним, я готов пойти на уступки. Тут следует руководствоваться здравым смыслом: для меня мои друзья важны, а экзамена по русскому у меня нет. Подчеркну, это мое и только мое решение, так как у меня нет никакого эмоционального отклика ни на одно, ни на второе написание.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky проще удалить, чем пояснить

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky У меня тоже нет никаких эмоциональных привязок. И я понимаю, что у вас есть знакомые с которыми вы общаетесь так, как вы с ними договорились. И вы с ними говорите в чате. А ваш пост зафлагует кто-то, кто зайдя в чат даже ничего не пишет, но будет флагать ваши сообщения, потому что это ЕГО обижает. А общаетесь вы и совсем другой человек. А влез в дискуссию и обиделся он. И правы не вы, а он, потому что чат - общественное, публичное место и согласно правилам вы должны ориентироваться не на личные настройки, а на цитирую "самого обидчивого". Кейс понятен?

Comment: @AK Возвращаясь в реальный мир. Какова статистика по данному вопросу? Сколько тревог мы получили на таких вопросах? Мы можем делать много мысленных экспериментов, но принимая решения нам нужно руководствоваться реальными данными. В список мы это добавили. Далее, можно к базе вопросов и базе чатов сделать запросы и посмотреть. Далее, тем сообществом, которое есть сейчас, делать вывод. Если в будущем появятся новые аргументы, поменяем решение! Не вижу предмета для споров на данном этапе.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: почему эти пункты вместе? Некоторые из этих комментариев могут быть не уместны на Stack Overflow, не являясь "оскорблениями". К примеру, *«иди гугли»* как правило не конструктивно (Stack Overflow это место назначения, куда гугл посылает -- если думаете что уже есть ответ, то закройте вопрос как дубликат) -- это демонстрирует отсутствие понимания целей и задач сайта, но "оскорблением" это с большой натяжкой можно назвать¶  *«Упоминание имён пользователей в вопросах, когда суть вопроса может быть обезличена, без потери смыслов.»* является плохой идеей...

Comment: ... (как недавние обсуждения в очередной раз демонстрируют), но опять таки причём здесь "оскорбления"? Акцент на людях, делает обсуждения менее продуктивными (вплоть до полной бесполезности), но само по себе упоминание имени, конечно оскорблением не является. Есть многие вещи, которые вредны для сайта, но которые не являются оскорблениями.

Comment: `Русское написание "на Украине" для украинцев и "Белоруссия" для белорусов, написание "в Украине" или "Беларусь" для русских`  это 
 неверно. Правила языка не имеет никакого отношения к предрассудкам. Кроме того сайт `ru`, (если плохо видно то 'RU` то есть РУССКИЙ) не `ua`, не `br`.   Сейчас забанем за  то что я по правилам языка на РУССКОМ сайте общяюсь, а потом забанем за то что я букву `'ы` вместо `i` написал?

Comment: "Упоминание имён пользователей в вопросах, когда суть вопроса может быть обезличена, без потери смыслов" Кто будет судить? Nicolas? Или может давайте выделим на это дело специальных полевых судей с неограниченой властью?

Comment: "называть конечных пользователей ПО "юзерами"" юзер это английское слово пользователь. Называть пользователя пользователем это оскорбление? О времена, о нравы...

Comment: "Фанатик — найдено здесь." То есть названия знака никого не смущает? Фанатик это не оскорбление, мне может и приятно было бы если б меня как нибудь так назвали. Это не оскорбления это характеристика человека который "безоговорочно следует убеждениям"

Comment: @AndrioSkur так смысл темы, видимо - собрать самые редкие и экзотические оскорбления. Поэтому неудивительно, что вы не понимаете. Вопрос про фанатика заминусован по самое немогу, а остальное - вообще непонятное нечто.

Comment: @AndrioSkur По поводу "в" против "на". Правила языка тут одни и в русском, и в украинском, и в белорусском языке. Когда говорится "на", то подразумевается скорее направление, например: "на Урале", "на север". Когда коворится "в", то подразумевается территория или место, например: "в городе", "в Питер". Поэтому когда вы пишете "на Украине" или "в Украине", украинцами это воспринимается как политика, а русскими в массе нет. Сами украинцы раньше говорили "на Украине" и никто не умирал от этого. Возмущает и огорчает что эти как-бы разногласия исскуственно создаются и навязываются.

Comment: @Cerbo, _на_ Украине оскорбительно, когда _на_ подчеркивается (например, интонационно) или есть желание оскорбиться.

Comment: В первый раз слышу, что фраза _в_ Украине может быть оскорбительной для русского. Это вообще реальный пример или надуманный?

Comment: @GreenDragon оскорбительной она конечно же не является, но может оказаться провокационной.

Comment: Если на Украине оскорбляются предлогом "на", то почему москвичи не оскорбляются, когда разные иностранцы коверкают название нашей столицы, а жители Лейпцига не требуют, чтобы мы произносили Ляйпциг? Про Алма-Ату, Таллин и пр. я уж помолчу.

Comment: "Русское написание "на Украине" для украинцев и "Белоруссия" для белорусов, написание "в Украине" или "Беларусь" для русских" - а уркаганов оскорбляет слово "садись, вместо него тоже стоит использовать "присядь".

Я из Украины и мне абсолютно всё равно кто как пишет. Я и сам чаще пишу "на Украине". Думаю, что людям, для которых это оскорбление, стоит сходить к психотерапевту.

Про юзеров полный бред.

Comment: @РашенБеар ...недаром ник Рашен выбрали

Answer (score -6):

## Оскорбительные для вас или ваших коллег выражения, которые не очевидны для людей вне вашего социума

(Пожалуйста, не забывайте добавлять пояснения!)

- Ты же программист! - может быть оскорбительным, что всех в ИТ гребут под 1 гребенку. В то же время стороннему человеку действительно неясно, в чем разница (как между фармацевтом и продавцем)
- Любые критические выражения, обобщающие действия одного человека на группу людей, в которой он состоит. Например: *"Выбранные владельцы комнаты закрепили это требование в боковой панели чата"*

Comment: Я еще ни разу не видел, чтобы «Ты же программист!» употреблялось где–либо в отрицательной коннотации. Видел, когда люди могли пояснять друзьям, что они не «ИТшники» (так как в большинстве компаний–разработчиков ПО ИТшник — человек, занимающийся базовыми вопросами администрирования и настройки конечных устройств). Поясните, пожалуйста, контекст?

Comment: Да.. сложно придумать пример .. без привлечения других оскорблений )

Comment: @alexolut Поясните, в чем вы видите оскорбление, в описанном вами подходе? Вроде бы это как раз уход от личностей, к общему выводу: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4790/ Переходить к обобщению с личностей, это не оскорбление, а рекомендация!

Comment: Это вам кажется, что это уход от личностей, а фактически это распространение утверждения на более широкую группу людей. "Вася пьёт водку, Вася русский → все русские пьют водку". Так понятнее?

Comment: @alexolut Вы делаете очень грубую ошибку. Пожалуйста, уберите _все_ из вашей фразы, и вам станет понятно о чем я. Далее, все зависит от контекста публикуемого: что мы описываем, пересечение или объединение свойств. Не вижу, что в случае объединения, в вашей фразе будет не верного.

Comment: Отнюдь. Вы почему-то спутали "обезличивание" и "обобщение". Если речь об одном человеке из группы, так и стоит писать "один человек из". Вы же демонизируете сразу всех членов группы. Это усиливает эффект от Ваших слов, но одновременно порочит непричастных. Это самое что ни на есть оскорбление. Очень грубое публичное оскорбление.

Comment: @alexolut "Выбранные владельцы комнаты закрепили это требование в боковой панели чата" я правильно понимаю, что правильнее было бы написать "Один из владельцев комнаты"?

Comment: @alexolut Пожалуйста, добавьте описанием к нужному пункту. Можно даже чуть более развернуто, описывающее, что есть, как я понял, в вашей интерпретации, обезличивание (объединение свойств группы) и обобщение (пересечение свойств группы). А также когда то и другое, по вашему мнению, можно/нельзя использовать.